# How to connect paystack payment gateway to my flutter e-commmerce app

Tags: flutter, woocommerce, e-commerce, paystack

I integrated Paystack payment gateway to  my Flutter-Woocommerce app. Everyhting works fine as in the integration and all.
I'm however having a little challenge in the e-commerce app I'm building while trying to pass the total amount of the cart to Paystack "amount". Whenever I do so, the Paystack popup payment window does not open. Please what could be wrong? Here is my code

```
chargeCard(BuildContext context) async {
    var cartItems = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context, listen: false);
      cartItems.fetchCartItems();
    var charge = Charge()
      ..amount =  (cartItems.totalAmount * 100) as int
      ..reference = _getReference()
      ..putCustomField('custom_id',
          '846gey6w') //to pass extra parameters to be retrieved on the response from Paystack
      ..email = 'support@jumbocheap.com';

    CheckoutResponse response = await plugin.checkout(
      context,
      method: CheckoutMethod.card,
      charge: charge,
    );
```

Please I need help. Thank you.

Comment: is cartItems.totalAmount an int or double?

Comment: @Josteve cartItems.totalAmount is a double